# Busqueda de paginas de Github

Tags: html5, web, github, buscador, github-pages

Estoy realizando un proyecto de una paginaweb, decidi subirla a github pages desde mi repositorio, pero solo puedo ingresar desde la url, es decir no es buscable a los navegadores,¿que puedo hacer para que mi pagina aparezca en resultados de busqueda sobre el tema que trata?
Si busco minipaint, se posiciona la pagina, pero cuando busco IETAC(el nombre de mi pagina) no aparece como sugerencia, solo puedo entrar pegando la URL, pero necesito que sea localizable como una busqueda normal[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Estoy haciendo una pagina web, la monte a git hub pages. Hay paginas alojadas en github, por ejemplo minipaint, yo escribo minipaint en el navegador y aparece el resultado, pero en mi pagina busco IETAC (asi se llama) y no me aparece en resultados, lo que quiero saber es como lograr que una pagina alojada en github tenga un buen posicionamiento, por ahora al parecer no lo tiene

Answer (score 0):

El posicionamiento de una pagina web depende de muchas cosas y mejorarlo realmente es un reto de DevOps y tienes que manejar estructuras de SEO, es por ello que responder tu pregunta no es una labor fácil y esta tiene muchas ramas, por ejemplo, tu pregunta se puede equiparar con: como programo en Python?

Como ves, es una pregunta muy abierta, la cual abarca muchas ramas y es casi imposible responderla por este medio.

Es por ello que te recomiendo buscar temas como posicionamiento Web y mejoras de SEO para una pagina Web

también te dejo el siguiente código que te ayudara a posicionar tu pagina Web a nivel Google, aunque esto no significa que inmediatamente saldrá TOP 1 en Google, recuerda es un tema muy grande y el posicionamiento de tu pagina depende de muchos factores.

```
<!-- Google -->
<meta itemprop="name" content="IETAC" />
<meta itemprop="description" content="{aqui pones la descripcion de tu pagina web}" />
<meta itemprop="image" content="{aqui pones un url con una imagen que muestre tu pagina web}" />
```

Espero haberte ayudado ;)

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda